# Hardware block to determine if a number is a multiple of 8

Tags: hardware

Can anyone suggest me an hardware block (I mean its structure/functional units) that is able to detect if a given number is a multiple of 8?

It seems easy but I haven't been unable to find a way to accomplish this.

Thanks

Answer (score 10, accepted):

If you have that number in binary (say, on a parallel bus), it's really easy: A binary number is divisible by 8 if the three least significant bits are 0. So you could simply do 
`NOT((bit0 OR bit 1) OR bit2)`.

Comment: Simple and elegant solution